# Connectedness of x-axis and graph of a positive continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm given the set $X=\{(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,+\infty)$. Let $G$ be the graph of $f$. How do I go about showing that $X\cup G$ is not connected?

I know that there will never be a point in $G$ of the form $(x,0)$, but I'm looking for a more formal way of showing disconnectedness.
Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: As you pointed out they are disjoint... Try to show that both sets are closed. (Notice that f is a continuous function into a Hausdorff space)

Comment: Elaborating on the comment of @PAM1499: if you show that both sets are closed, since they are disjoint, the complement of $X$ in $X \cup G$ is $G$ and the complement of $G$ in $X \cup G$ is $X$ showing that both sets are open and disjoint and cover all $X \cup G$. So, if both sets are closed, both sets are open and you get two non-empty disjoint open sets that cover your space i.e. your space is not connected.